# vba code to update status based on each macro run

Tags: excel

I've 3 macros

- macro 1 for Final inputsheet
- macro 2 for process 1 sheet
- macro 3 for plot sheet

Is it possible to update a cell for example in status sheet cell B2 when macro 1 gets completed then based on B2 macro 2 will start and once macro 2 is completed it will update B3 , based on B3 value macro 3 will run and once macro 3 is completed it will update B4.

is it possible?

I can run the macro based on value change in a particular cell but how do i update a cell when a macro run is completed?

```
Sub lastRow()

Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
Dim wsS3 As Worksheet 'sheet3

Dim lastR As Long, lastC As Long

Set wsS1 = Sheets("Input")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("Final Input")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("Status")

With wsS1
lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With wsS2
lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill 
 Destination:=Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)

  With wsS3
 .Range ("B2" = completed)



End With
End Sub
```

Comment: To update a cell you would have your macro set the cell's value.  Why this way though?  Why not have your macros call each other directly and pass whatever value(s) are needed?

Comment: status is required that why using the status method

Comment: Then you can update the cell before calling the next macro.

Comment: @TimWilliams is there a code that i can add to an existing macro so that it will update once the process is completed?

Comment: but then i'll have to update the cell manually ... i dont want to update it manually ..its should be automatic

Comment: whatever you put at the end of your macro will run when the method is "completed"

Comment: what should i add to the end of the macro? @TimWilliams

Comment: @peh any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187041/discussion-between-j-doe-and-tim-williams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add this to your code and the status sheet will be updated for the first macro

```
wsS3.Range("B2").Value = "complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
    ...do stuff
    Range("a1")=10  'log progress
    Macro2 10       'run next step, passing in some info    
End Sub

Sub Macro2(input)
    ...do stuff with 'input'
    Range("a2")=20
    Macro3 20
End Sub

'etc etc
```

Comment: i dont want to pass info to the next macro ...i just want to update the status sheet based on once the macro is completed it will change the cell value of B2 as completed